# Create ghost dvd or image of linux suse

Tags: linux, opensuse

I am stuck in a problem of Linux suse and need help on the same. My problem is mentioned below.

As per my client requirement, I have to create a ghost dvd or image dvd of the Linux suse 11 operating system with the softwares installed and configuration in it. So, when user will enter the cd into there machine, first system will load SUSE and then will configure all the softwares without any human intervention.

So, whats is the process to create the same?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In my opinion this is not a question and not for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are instructions on SuSE wiki:

http://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Live_USB_stick